# Adding a third party script to a Next.js application not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following script that I've tried adding it to _document.js, then to app.js and then to the specific page

```
<Script src="https://anywebsite.ai/chatbot/chatbot.js"></Script>
  <Script 
    id="show-chatbot"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
      __html: `
        var _chatbot = window._chatbot = window._chatbot || []
        _chatbot.website = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        _chatbot.domainName = 'Stamma'
        _chatbot.frameMode = true // Set this to true if you want to display the window directly
        _chatbot.width = '400px'
        _chatbot.height = '500px'
        _chatbot.title = 'Stikii AI'
        _chatbot.hello = 'Welcome. What would you like to know?'
        _chatbot.placeholder = 'Ask anything'
        _chatbot.replying = 'Stikii AI is thinking...'
      ` 
    }}
  />
```

This script should add a chatbot to a div with # chatbot that I've added in one of the components of my application, but nothing happens.

I have then tried to append the script from within a component like the below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const anywebsiteScript = document.createElement('script');
    anywebsiteScript.src = 'https://anywebsite.ai/chatbot/chatbot.js';
    anywebsiteScript.async = true;

    const innerScript = document.createElement('script');
    innerScript.innerHTML = `
      var _chatbot = window._chatbot = window._chatbot || [];
      _chatbot.website = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      _chatbot.domainName = 'Stamma';
      _chatbot.frameMode = true; // Set this to true if you want to display the window directly
      _chatbot.width = '400px';
      _chatbot.height = '500px';
      _chatbot.title = 'Stikii AI';
      _chatbot.hello = 'Welcome. What would you like to know?';
      _chatbot.placeholder = 'Ask anything';
      _chatbot.replying = 'Stikii AI is thinking...';
    `;
    innerScript.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(anywebsiteScript);
    document.body.appendChild(innerScript);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(anywebsiteScript);
      document.body.removeChild(innerScript);
    };
}, []);
```

But that also did nothing.

Is there a way to make the script work in a Next.js application?

---

### Update

Here is the full component for reference

```
import Script from "next/script"

const Header = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`py-3 container-fluid`}>
                <div className="row justify-content-between">
                    <div className="col-auto">
                        
                        <Script
                            id="show-chatbot"
                            src="https://anywebsite.ai/chatbot/chatbot.js"
                            onLoad={() => {
                            var _chatbot = window._chatbot = window._chatbot || [];
                            _chatbot.website = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                            _chatbot.domainName = "Stamma";
                            _chatbot.frameMode = true; // Set this to true if you want to display the window directly
                            _chatbot.width = "400px";
                            _chatbot.height = "500px";
                            _chatbot.title = "Stikii AI";
                            _chatbot.hello = "Welcome. What would you like to know?";
                            _chatbot.placeholder = "Ask anything";
                            _chatbot.replying = "Stikii AI is thinking...";
                            }}
                        />
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the script inside the `_document.js` file but rather inside your page component or your `_app.js` if it is required on all pages. You can then add the script like this:

```
import Script from "next/script";

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        id="show-chatbot"
        src="https://anywebsite.ai/chatbot/chatbot.js"
        onLoad={() => {
          var _chatbot = (window._chatbot = window._chatbot || []);
          _chatbot.website = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
          _chatbot.domainName = "Stamma";
          _chatbot.frameMode = true; // Set this to true if you want to display the window directly
          _chatbot.width = "400px";
          _chatbot.height = "500px";
          _chatbot.title = "Stikii AI";
          _chatbot.hello = "Welcome. What would you like to know?";
          _chatbot.placeholder = "Ask anything";
          _chatbot.replying = "Stikii AI is thinking...";
        }}
      />
      // ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Also check out [this section](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script#props) inside the official documentation to see more about the `Script` component and its usage.

Comment: Thank you for your help but when I add the script in the component in the way you suggested I get the error ReferenceError: _chatbot is not defined. If I add that js snippet to a plain html page it works correctly.

Comment: This means that the _chatbot variable you are trying to access inside the window object is not defined. Are you sure this code snippet is valid?

Comment: Well yes, it's working here on this simple html page http://stikii-chatbot.clientapproval2.co.uk

Comment: Can you update your question with the update page code? It's really hard to figure out what the problem is with just the snippet you have provided.

Comment: Sure - I've added the stripped out component. That is all there is really, the chatbot should appear in the Header component. If you check the source code for the HTML test view-source:http://stikii-chatbot.clientapproval2.co.uk/ you'd see that that's all there is to add, the chatbot.js file and some settings. I can't figure out why next.js doesn't like that script